# Spring Data JPA intelligence not working in Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have set up a spring boot project with Spring Data JPA, but I am not seeing the intelligence for Spring data jpa.
[image]

The screen shot shows the issue, my Restaurant entity has a variable call `restaurantAddress`, I am trying to let intelliJ help me finish the coding but no intelligence shows up.

My project set up is as follows:

Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.mycompany"})
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>food</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Dependencies for RESTful Web Services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Dependencies for JPA Data Persistence -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--JDBC-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>food</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have Spring Data plugin installed on my IntelliJ 15, prject settings:

[image]

Comment: Actually just noticed the same issue.  I don't recall is ever working.  It is very dynamic given the many options when creating a query.

Comment: this blog shows they do have support as in STS but we are not being able to configure in the versions that we are currently use ( i guess 15) : http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/11/enjoy-spring-data-jpa-in-intellij-11/

Comment: i've opened up a bounty for this. hope we will get help from community ..

Comment: Are you sure you have installed and also ENABLED following plugins? `File` -> `Settings` -> `Plugins` and check/enable plugin "Database Tools and SQL", "Hibernate Support", "Java EE: EJB, JPA, Servlets" and "Spring Data".

Comment: @lu_ko suggestion worked for me as I didn't have Spring Data plugin enabled. Thanks!

Comment: I made the silly mistake of thinking it did not work; but really I had not added the dynamic method to the Repository interface... If it helps anyone.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding `JavaEE Persistence` framework support. Just right click on the project, select `Add Framework Support` and then scroll down to find the `JavaEE Persistence`, then enable the checkbox and hit OK:

[image: Enabling JavaEE Persistence Support]
<sup>*Adding JavaEE Persistence Facet*</sup>

It will add a `persistence.xml` file, you can delete it. Finally your auto completions will be back:

[image: Moment of truth]
<sup>*Moment of truth*</sup>

**Update** You can also enable `JPA` facet in the `Project Structure`. First, press `Ctrl Alt Shift S` or go to `Files > Project Structure`. Hit the `Add` button and in the menu, then select `JPA`:

[image]
<sup>*Adding JPA Facet*</sup>

And finally hit `OK`.

Comment: I do not have the option "JavaEE Persistence" listed on the "Add Framework Support Dialog" . I added the dependency org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final to POM but it is still not showing up.. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've already added JPA facet. But the intelligence is still not working.

Comment: Which version of intellij? Did you check your plugins?

Comment: Intellij version is : 15.0.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102897/discussion-between-gt-ebuddy-and-ali-dehghani).

Comment: @David Which version of IntelliJ?

Comment: 2016.1.2 is the latest one..Is your project is a Spring Boot project?Some versions of IntelliJ does not support Spring Boot very well.

Comment: If you already has JPA framework support but no completion, you should remove it and add again. It will(?) generate new configs. Worked for me.

Comment: @anibyl Adding a totally useless `persistence.xml` sometimes will do the trick, I guess

Comment: Intellij 2018.1.5 same issue, the @UsievaładKimajeŭ suggestion works for me. i.e remove Spring Data plugin, restart then enable it.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!

Comment: Not working for me. Removed the config multiple times. Do I have to set it to hibernate or no provider?

Comment: Usievaład Kimajeŭ' s suggestion worked for me. Remove and add Spring Data again.

Comment: Just add once & restart your device, it works for me